# checking duplicate entries in rows in data frame

Tags: r

my data can have many columns from ID2 to ID1000 and for these columns on data frame i want to create a functionality which can check in every rows if any entry comes more than one.

No entry should come more than once.

so in my data frame **A0012** comes twice in second row. and in eighth row **AB982** comes twice. whenever any entry comes more than one then it should show as duplicate entry.

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921",NA,"KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,Ajay","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"),
                 ID2 = c("A0011","A0011","A0011","A0011","A0011","A0012","AB702","AB328","AC728","AC314","AC742","AC919","AC062","AD712","AD021","AD920"),
                 ID3 = c("A0012","A0012","A0012","A0012","A0012","A0013","AB712","AB712","AB702","AB328","AC314","AC728","AB702","AB712","AC742","AC919"),
                 ID4 = c(NA,"A0013","A0013","A0013","AB982","AB982",NA,"AB982","A0013","A0012","A0012","A0012","A0012",NA,"A0013","A0012"),
                 ID5 =c(NA,"A0012","AB012","AB012",NA,"AB702",NA,"A0013",NA,"A0011","A0011",NA,"A0011",NA,NA,NA),
                 ID6 = c(NA,NA,NA,"AB982",NA,NA,NA,"A0012",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 ID7 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"A0011",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 ID8 =c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"AB982",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

The output should be look like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fun add column with number of duplicas in whole row

```
cbind(df, 
      dupl = apply(df,MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(duplicated(x,incomparables=NA)) )) ## use df[,-c(1:3)] in apply if you want only check IDs
```

and point 'duplicates available'

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(df, 
      dupl = apply(df,MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(duplicated(x,incomparables=NA)) )) %>% ## use df[,-c(1:3)] in apply if you want only check IDs
  mutate(dupl = ifelse(dupl >0 , 'duplicates available', ''))
```

Comment: getting error Error in apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(duplicated(x, incomparables = NA))) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: are you sure you are using table as `df`, not a vector?

Comment: could you check what `dim(df)` return?

Comment: [1] 16 10 this is output

Comment: ... so this Error its not possible for that `df`. to meke sure try: `base::apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) base::sum(base::duplicated(x,incomparables=NA)))`